# Preventing list items from displaying whilst overlay images load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 6 divs .box that contain an unordered list and images with the images being absolutely positioned above each list. Is there a way I can make sure the content under the image isnt revealed whilst the content boxes fade in?

http://jsfiddle.net/NKFgC/

Kyle

Comment: Wait what is actually wrong with the jsfiddle you have? It seems it already does what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, you can use callback functions. Keep the content hidden (display none or visibility hidden) and use something like:

```
$(element).fadeIn(300, function() {
    //show/hide content
});
```

here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NKFgC/4/

Answer (score 1):

Hide the container object with CSS *display: none;* until you're ready to show it, then change  the display value with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Fix stop with `stop(true, true)`

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/NKFgC/1/

Comment: @kyllle remember to select an accepted answer when you find one